# Is there any available xslt schemas which produces json-api compliant json?

Tags: php, json, xslt, json-api

I am developing one API service which accepts data in simple XML format and should produce [JSON-API](https://jsonapi.org/) compliant requests from it.

As far as I see xslt3.0 provides new function [xml-to-json](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-xml-to-json) which makes possible to create json from xml in runtime using correct xslt stylesheet.

Is there any xsl schemas exist for these purposes?

Comment: What do you mean by *"xsl schemas"*?

Comment: I mean existing xsl files which do the job

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: Not really. Jsonapi has it is own standard which is not equal to input data. I am also searching a way to not to do it on php because I probably will share it between other services

Comment: @Dhrubo Saha: The question is not about a random API that serves JSON but an API that implements [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/). The naming is so confusing...